# Grab available artifact versions in jenkins parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy, artifactory

I want to have an ability in Jenkins build fetch available artefacts versions (i use Artifactory to store code packed in .zip) and put them as a dropdown list, so i can select the version i want to use with this build.

Could you give an example how to do this best way?

Answer (score 0):

To do so, i use jenkins plugin [Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) and add reactive parameter into the job. This gives me an ability to select what Environment to use, and based on it fetch available artifacts from artifactory

[image]

Job configuration:
[image]

Groovy code used in "Active choice" parameters:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?:develop|master|function)_(?:latest|[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+).*)")

def repository_dev = "https://repo.nibr.novartis.net/artifactory/api/storage/nibr-generic/intuence_discovery/idaw_health_checker/develop/"
def repository_tst = "https://repo.nibr.novartis.net/artifactory/api/storage/nibr-generic/intuence_discovery/idaw_health_checker/release/"
def repository_prd = "https://repo.nibr.novartis.net/artifactory/api/storage/nibr-generic/intuence_discovery/idaw_health_checker/master/"

try {
    if (DEPLOY_TO == "dev") {
        versions = "curl -s $repository_dev"
    }
    else if (DEPLOY_TO == "tst") {
        versions = "curl -s $repository_tst"
    }
    else if (DEPLOY_TO == "prd") {
        versions = "curl -s $repository_prd"
    }

    def proc = versions.execute()
    proc.waitFor()
    def output = proc.in.text
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def artifactsJsonObject = jsonSlurper.parseText(output)
    def dataArray = artifactsJsonObject.children
    List<String> artifacts = new ArrayList<String>()
    for(item in dataArray) {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(item.uri)
        while (m.find()) {
            artifacts.add(m.group());
        }
    }
    return artifacts
} 

catch (Exception e) {
    return ["There was a problem fetching the artifacts", e]
}
```